# Laravel Encryption/Decryption model data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a new project that stores guest information. For security I thought it would be cool to store all the personal data in the database with encryption. Is there any specific workflow for doing this. Essentially setting encryption on certain Model fields and having everything just work. Thinking about it, I feel like its not so simple but I thought I would throw it out there.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite straightforward in Laravel. All you have to make sure is that your accessors & mutators(for the properties that you want to encrypt) use the encryption.

More about accessors & mutators here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

For example, if you want to encrypt the property email for your model, add the following:

```
//mutator
public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{

    $this->attributes['email'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);

}


//accessor

public function getNameFirstAttribute($value)
{
    if (is_null($value)) {

        return $value;

    }

    return Crypt::decrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: i tried the same but got some errors not working this

Comment: hi i want his for whole columns and this will get lot of tome to work is there another solutions like   protected $encryptable = [
        'first',
        'last',
        'email',
    ];

Answer (score 1):

You can use accessors and mutators. They will encrypt data when you store the data and decrypt it when you fetch by itself.